# Unwanted characters when printing a C string

Tags: c, c-strings

For the most part my code below does what I want. The only issue is it is printing extra unwanted non-ASCII characters in front of the string.

I tried printing the string inside the `longestConsec()` function and found that it already contains the unwanted characters so I know that the problem is in the function.

Additionally, I tried looping through `res` (using the length that I assigned to it with `malloc()`) to set the characters to whitespace; this worked but I don't want leading and trailing whitespace and I don't want to write an algorithm to remove it if it's not necessary.

If I did something to cause these unwanted characters to appear then I would prefer to fix that than to work around by setting everything to whitespace and then trimming it.

Any help would be appreciated.

### Output:

```
Expected Output:threefourthreefour
Output: ÉmthreefourÉmthreefour
Output with white space replacement:          threefour         threefour
```

### Code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* longestConsec(char* strarr[], int n, int k)
{
    int i = 0;
    int longest = 0;
    int longestIndex = 0;
    for(; i < n; i++) {
        if(longest < strlen(strarr[i])) {
            longestIndex = i;
            longest = strlen(strarr[i]);
        }
    }
    //printf("%d", longestIndex);
    int length = 0;
    i = longestIndex;
    int j = 0;
    for(; i < n && j < k; i++, j++) {
        length += strlen(strarr[i]);
    }
    char* res = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    int m = 0;
    for(; m < length; m++) {
        res[m] = ' ';
    }

    i = longestIndex;
    j = 0;

    //printf("%s", res);
    for(; i < n && j < k; i++, j++) {
        strcat(res, strarr[i]);
    }
    printf("%s", res);
    return res;
}



int main()
{
    char* strs[10] = {"One", "Two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};
    printf("%s", longestConsec(strs, 10, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc` does not return you valid string, If you for loop where you are adding spaces, you are missing ending zero. Add `res[m] = 0;` after for loop.

Comment: Make sure the allocated memory location is zeroed i.e. use `bzero()`, this might also help you get away from unwanted characters.

Comment: @rakib_ `bzero()` is depricated.

Comment: Or simply call `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: adding res[m] = 0 after in the loop worked. Thanks.

Comment: @babon - personally I like `bzero`. It tells what it does.

Comment: when posting a question about a runtime problem, as this question is, post a [mcve].

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: regarding: `char* res = malloc(length * sizeof(char));`  1) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1. multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect and just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing that expression.  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding these two statements: `char* strs[10] = {"One", "Two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};
printf("%s", longestConsec(strs, 10, 2));`  1) don't use 'magic' numbers in the code, they make the code very inflexible and the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest using an `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) 2) let the compiler do the work.  Suggest: `char* strs[] = {"One", "Two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};
printf("%s", longestConsec(strs, sizeof(strs)/sizeof(strs[0]), 2));

Comment: The posted code is missing the necessary `#include` statements.  Are you expecting use to guess as to which header files you actually used?

Comment: the posted code contains a memory leak because the pointer returned from `malloc()` is not being passed to `free()`.   Do not leave 'cleanup' to the OS.  Such sloppy habits will burn you, especially when you are programming embedded code.

Comment: variable and parameter names should indicate `content` or `usage`  (or better, both).  parameter names like `n` and `k` are meaningless even in the current context.

Comment: regarding: `for(; i < n && j < k; i++, j++)`   the variable `k` contains 2 so this will accumulate ONLY the lengths of the first 2 entries from the `strs[]` array.   Probably not what you want.

Comment: regarding: `for(; m < length; m++)
    {
        res[m] = ' ';
    }` suggest removing this code block.  It is not helping and calling `calloc()` rather than `malloc()` would do the same job.

Comment: the function: `strlen()` returns the index to the NUL byte in the array of characters.  indexes start at 0, so to use this returned value as a parameter to `malloc()`, need to add 1 to allow for the NUL terminator byte.

Comment: note: the pair `seven` `eight`  is longer than the pair `three` `four`  so the overall logic is not correct.

Comment: since the call to `malloc()` did not allocate enough characters to allow room for the trailing NUL byte, the loop that is calling `strcat()` is writing past the end of the allocated memory block.  This results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with the leading 'unexpected' characters is because the call to `strcat()` begins placing characters WHERE it encounters a NUL byte.

That could be anywhere,in memory (I.E. undefined behavior with out setting the NUL byte in the code.)

Rather than the loop that sets all the bytes in the allocated memory nor calling `calloc()`, a MUCH BETTER method would be to set the FIRST byte of the allocated memory to NUL  I.E.

```
res[0] = '\0';
```

Then the following call(s) to `strcat()` will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind shows this quite straightforwardly:

```
==19471== Invalid read of size 1
==19471==    at 0x4C2EAA4: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19471==    by 0x108863: longestConsec (46557761.c:34)
==19471==    by 0x10892A: main (46557761.c:45)
==19471==  Address 0x51d5049 is 0 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd
==19471==    at 0x4C2BBEF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19471==    by 0x108805: longestConsec (46557761.c:23)
==19471==    by 0x10892A: main (46557761.c:45)
```

You have created an unterminated string with at least `length` characters in a block of size `length` you allocated.  Appending will necessarily overrun the buffer, simply while looking for the end of the existing string.

Instead of writing `length` spaces, you should write a single NUL character, to form an empty string.

BTW, you should fix your compilation warnings (ensure you have at least `-Wall -Wextra` or equivalent).

---

### Fixed code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *longestConsec(const char *strarr[], unsigned int n, unsigned int k)
{
    unsigned int longest = 0;
    unsigned int longestIndex = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0;  i < n;  ++i) {
        unsigned int len = strlen(strarr[i]);
        if (longest < len) {
            longestIndex = i;
            longest = len;
        }
    }

    unsigned int lastIndex = longestIndex + k;
    if (lastIndex > n) {
        lastIndex = n;
    }

    unsigned int length = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = longestIndex;  i < lastIndex;  ++i) {
        length += strlen(strarr[i]);
    }
    char *res = malloc(length + 1);
    res[0] = '\0';

    for (unsigned int i = longestIndex;  i < lastIndex;  ++i) {
        strcat(res, strarr[i]);
    }
    return res;
}


#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char const *strs[10] = {"One", "Two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};
    char *longest = longestConsec(strs, 10, 2);
    printf("%s\n", longest);
    free(longest);
    return 0;
}
```